# Making a direct API call from WearOS watch over WiFi without phone connectivity

Tags: wear-os, android-wear-data-api, android-wear-2.0

I am not Android/WearOS savvy so apologize in advance to those who are eager to push down arrow button.

I am looking to put together a proof of concept that would read sensor data from Android/WearOS watch and send it to an Azure API EndPoint over WiFi without needing or intervention of phone. As we understand that latest WearOS devices can directly connect to WiFi.

First of all can WearOS watch make a direct api call over WiFi? If not then please advise!

If so has anyone done similar work or point me in the right direction. Please share sample code or how to tutorial.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the official documentation page for this? https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/network-access

It has a step-by-step walkthrough of the process of network communication from Wear OS, as well as sample code.